# Debug Tests in NG Test

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI and VSCode but none of my breakpoints in my spec files seem to be getting hit when I run `ng test`?

Do I need to do some config?

Comment: did you try debugging via chrome dev tools? you can do this as a workaround until you find the correct way to do it. as far as I know, you need to configure the .vscode/launch.json file, I just don't know with what

Comment: Thats basically what I'm asking... it works fine for debugging my code... just don't know/understand how to do this for ng test!

Comment: So, you want to run unit tests in debug mode? Are you attempting to debug unit tests?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Update for Angular version 9**

The source files have been moved but you can still debug this way if you do the following steps

- In devtools, select the sources tab
- Press CTRL + P
- Type in the name of the file you want to debug

[image]

**Valid for versions below 9**

The other answers are completely valid answers but having been using Angular for around 18 months now I tend to do it in the browser - chrome tools!

Run ng test then f12 and find the spec file via the webpack context. Add a breakpoint(s) and refresh and it will hit said breakpoints. As per screenshot

[image]

Comment: what about "DEBUG" button in UI. What is the functionality of it ?

Comment: this does not work for me. Webpack only loads styles (both directly on karma and the /debug.html).

Comment: yeah I've just upgraded to Angular v9 and the ability to do this has disappeared

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, I can find the source files, but breakpoints aren't working...

Comment: you must be doing something differently. 100% works for me and my colleagues ... and from the CLI team guidance as per the ticket i raised for the original issue... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17792#issuecomment-634022498

Answer (score 45):

This is what worked for me with:

- Angular 9.0.6 + Visual Studio Code 1.43.2
- Angular 8.2.13 + Visual Studio Code 1.39.2
- Angular 7, Angular CLI 1.0.* and Chrome on Windows 7.

---

### Change configuration files

In your project root directory open `karma.conf.js`. Right after `singleRun: false` add `,` followed by this section:

```
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeDebug: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [ '--remote-debugging-port=9333' ]
      }
    }
```

Add configuration to `.vscode/launch.json`.

- For versions 8.* - 9.* (note `"pathMapping` section!):

  ```
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Unit tests",
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 9333,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "pathMapping": {
      "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  },
  ```
- For version 7.*:

  ```
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Unit tests",
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 9333,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
  ```

---

### Start debugging

1. Run `ng test --browsers ChromeDebug`
2. Wait for Chrome browser to start. You will see something like this in command line:

   ```
   01 06 2017 16:07:29.276:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser ChromeDebug with unlimited concurrency
   ```
3. Set the breakpoint in one of your `.spec.ts` files.
4. In Visual Studio Code choose `Unit tests` debug configuration and hit F5 ("Start Debugging" button).
5. Press `Shift+Ctrl+F5` or refresh the Chrome window to rerun the tests and hit the breakpoint.

---

### For convenience

You can also modify your package.json and add a new script:

```
"test-debug": "ng test --browsers ChromeDebug",
```

Then next time you want to start `ng test` with debugging just run:

```
npm run test-debug
```

---

References:

- [Debugging Jasmine Unit tests running with Karma runner in VS Code](https://wannabeegeek.com/2017/04/07/debugging-jasmine-unit-tests-running-with-karma-runner-in-vs-code/)
- [Debugging Karma tests with VSCode](http://blog.mlewandowski.com/Debugging-Karma-tests-with-VSCode.html)
- [Angular CLI 8.1.3 `Debug Unit Tests` configuration - Unverified breakpoint](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/issues/225)
- [microsoft/vscode-recipes - Chrome Debugging with Angular CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI)

Comment: Why do we have to run `ng test` manually? Can it not be a `preLaunchTask`? I've tried and haven't been able to get it to work very well but then again I don't really know what I am doing.

Comment: @steinybot: I found all this `start something on each debugging session` workflow quite annoying, that's why I prefer to start it manually and this is why I use `"request": "attach"` instead of `"request": "launch"`. I don't use `preLaunchTask` for any of my debug configurations, but I can try it out and play with it. What did you try so far? Do you have GitHub gist or something similar?

Comment: A good option to use is `ng test --browsers ChromeDebug --watch=true`, wait until the tests run and then you have time to attach the debugger.

Comment: Spot on Andrei. This weeks for me even now. I've read so many posts over the last few days that simply do not work.

Answer (score 13):

In the new release of **VSCode (1.14.0)** they follow this [recipe](https://github.com/weinand/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI):

You can debug the Angular App entirely ( including the unit tests ), the recipe is straightforward.

Comment: Recipe should be updated and I create a bug report, but there is not much activity right now, so I didn't event get an answer to `Should I create pull request?` question. Anyway, working configuration is here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/issues/225 (tested it on Angular CLI 8.3.17 and Angular 8.2.13 today).

Comment: This solution is explicit for VSCode (1.14.0) or before. So, is correct. Look at the answer of A-Sharabiani, maybe that could help.

Comment: This solution worked for me.
Angular 11.2.4, Angular CLI 11.2.3, VS Code 1.55.0, Node.js 12.181.3

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to the other answers:

- Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI) @titusfx mentioned.
- In the terminal run `ng test`.
- In Visual Studio Code debug view select `ng test` from the drop down.
- you might need to refresh the browser if cannot hit the break points the first time.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

You can simply add a 'debugger'
where you want to debug and run

```
ng test
```

When the chrome browser opens, turn on the dev tools and it will stop on your 'debugger'