# Angular | Jasmine Unit Test | Karma | VSCode Debug

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, karma-runner

As part of an Angular app I am trying to debug Jasmine test cases run by Karma in VSCode. I have referenced the below links and made the following changes

http://blog.mlewandowski.com/Debugging-Karma-tests-with-VSCode.html

[Debug Tests in NG Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916649/debug-tests-in-ng-test)

**Karma.conf.js**

```
browsers: ['chromeDebug'],
singleRun: false,
customLaunchers: {
  chromeDebug: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: [ '--remote-debugging-port=9333' ]
  }
},
```

**Behavior**

While running **ng test** the browser is launched but the **[web-server]** is not running and serving the files. Below is the comparison between the logs

**Default** - without using customLaunchers

```
[36m01 04 2018 10:08:37.837:DEBUG [web-server]: [39mInstantiating middleware
[36m01 04 2018 09:43:11.281:DEBUG [web-server]: 
[39mserving: /Users/.../Documents/Workspace/xyz-web-app/node_modules/
karma/static/client.html
```

**Debug** - while using custLaunchers

```
[36m01 04 2018 10:08:37.578:DEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading inlined plugin (defining launcher:chromeDebug).
[36m01 04 2018 10:08:37.837:DEBUG [web-server]: [39mInstantiating middleware
[33m01 04 2018 10:09:07.786:WARN [karma]: [39mNo captured browser, open http://localhost:9333/
[33m01 04 2018 10:10:48.118:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 120000 ms, killing.
```

During the Debug more since the [web-server] is not able to server the files *[web-server]: 
    [39mserving: /Users/.../Documents/Workspace/xyz-web-app/node_modules/
    karma/static/client.html*

I have tried to increase captureTimeout with little success. I believe if the issue might be with additional configuration required for customLunchers. Any suggestions or direction on the fixing this will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First, without the changes, does ng test work ? Second, you added a link (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI ) Did you try that ? Because the first link is 1 year old and the second is updated 11 days ago

Comment: ng test works fine with default Chrome, its only when I use the customLaunchers I am facing the issue