# Not able to debug source code while running unit test cases angular v9

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular9

I am using angular v9.
I am able to debug unit test cases in browser using ng test command.
However, some source code methods i need to debug in order to inspect why unit test cases are failing, for that i am trying to add breakpoint, but not able to add them where as some source code method i am able to debug.
any idea?

Comment: Do you mean the `debugger;` instruction ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/debugger

Answer (score 0):

There's a thread regarding to [debug tests in ng test].([Debug Tests in NG Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916649/debug-tests-in-ng-test))

Note: Assuming that you are using **Google Chrome** as a test browser.